# Cloud Firestore serving outdated data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In the last day, I have started having trouble with Cloud Firestore serving outdated data to my Flutter app running on android.  I tried clearing the cache for the app, uninstalling/reinstalling with no success.  Still Firestore kept serving the outdated data.  Then I tried disabling persistence with the `persistenceEnabled: false` at startup.  It stopped serving the outdated data, but now it doesn't return current data that should be returned!  Any suggestions to check what might be going on?

Edit: I should mention that this is happening on a collectionGroup query for which the index has been built.  I've checked the database rules, and there are not any denies or errors resulting from this query.

Comment: add some logs..

Comment: @griffins what logs are you referring to?  Where can I find them?

Comment: if youre using vs code ctrl +j debug console share whats printed there, on android studio at the bottom debug console

Comment: Thanks @griffins, your suggestion let me to the logcat where I found this error: `Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.`. Turns out I changed one of my queries recently and needed to update the index.  To bad this error wasn't more clear.  Chased my tail for a while.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I changed one of my Collection group queries recently and needed to update the index.  So if you have Cloud Firestore queries that are acting erratic like mine was, check out your logcat or console log for an error like this:

`Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.`

Firestore is supposed to provide a URL to build the appropriate index, but in my case the URL did not appear so I had to [add it manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).

Comment: I'm facing the same problem but despite adding indexing, it still doesn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68269995/how-do-i-index-queries-in-firebase