# How do I index queries in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get documents that contain location fields that match with the user's location using:

```
getLocationListings(placemark) async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup("posts")
        .where('location', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: placemark.locality)
        .get();
    setState(() {
      posts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.
```

Yet I have created indexes at the console as [image: Screenshot of indexes created]

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Something might be wrong in the indexes you created for that collection group. I would recommend you to delete the index you created and run the function again, it's going to throw an error and if you were to check android device logs by executing

```
adb logcat
```

on the terminal you will see a message like this:

> 'FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: [https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/XXXXXXXXX/firestore/indexes?create_composite=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'](https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/XXXXXXXXX/firestore/indexes?create_composite=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%27).

Just click on the link and create the proposed index, this should fix the issue.

Comment: When I hover over the index, I don't even get the option to delete as I should. This is my first attempt with Firebase and it's really frustrating.

Comment: Hmm, might be a problem with the Firebase UI, can you give it a try using the GCP UI, following the steps shared in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing#delete_a_single-field_index_exemption)?